# Updating DataFrame row by row in for loop using column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame df which contains three columns: 'val_1', 'val_2', and 'winning_val'. 'Val_1' and 'val_2' are filled with values, and 'winning_val' is full of NaNs. I want this for loop to cycle through df and fill in the 'winning_val' column.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
            df.at[i, 'winning_val'] = find_winner(row)
```

This code does not modify df, and keeps the 'winning_val' column full of NaNs. I also need to be able to access the column by the String name and not by index.

Comment: What do you want to fill the `NaN` values with?

Comment: @HS-nebula find_winner(row) will give a value based on the values of 'val_1' and 'val_2'.

Comment: What does `find_winner` do?

Comment: Also, please provide some sample data, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @HS-nebula find_winner compares val_1 and val_2 and returns the winner of these values. This method functions as intended. The issue is that the DataFrame 'df' does not stay modified after the for loop ends.

Comment: Please add your `find_winner` code to your question, the error is likely there.

Comment: @HS-nebula Pretend instead `find_winner(row)` was replaced with a value, like `1`. The for loop will not replace every entry in column `winning_val` with `1`.

Comment: It's hard to help you without a sample dataframe and without seeing `find_winner`. In a sample dataframe I created, I can run what you have with the line `df.at[i, 'winning_val'] = 1` and it works fine. That leads me to think the issue is with your data or your `find_winner` function, but I can't help further unless I know what those look like.

Comment: @Wilhelm I ran your code on a random dataframe and I can find no problems. What issue are you having, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
df['winning_val'] = df.apply(find_winner, axis=1)
```

where `find_winner` is a function defined to process a row of your dataframe, for example:

```
def find_winner(row):
    return max(row['val_1'], row['val_2'])
```